# symfony doctrine2 store entity as json

Tags: symfony, serialization, doctrine-orm, symfony5, php-8

I have an entity with several properties that could be grouped together, are crucial for it's usage and I won't ever have to index them.
I thought about storing them in separate class, just for the order.
I'd like to store the object of this class inside a text column in a json representation.
I tried something like this:

```
class Market
{
    /**
     * @var Fee
     * @ORM\Column(type="json")
     */
    protected Fee $fee;
(...)
}
```

and the Fee class:

```
class Fee implements Serializable
{
    private float $taker;
    private float $maker;

    public function __construct(float $taker, float $maker)
    {
        $this->taker = $taker;
        $this->maker = $maker;
    }

    /**
     * @return float
     */
    public function getTaker(): float
    {
        return $this->taker;
    }

    /**
     * @return float
     */
    public function getMaker(): float
    {
        return $this->maker;
    }

    public function serialize()
    {
        return json_encode(
            [
                'taker' => $this->getTaker(),
                'maker' => $this->getMaker(),
            ]
        );
    }

    public function unserialize($serialized)
    {
        $decoded = json_decode($serialized, true);
        $this->taker = $decoded['taker'];
        $this->maker = $decoded['maker'];
    }
}
```

I'd like to have something like this in final column "fee":

```
{
 "taker": 0.0016,
 "maker": 0.004
}
```

but instead I always get an empty json `{}`.
Please advise how to do what I intend to.
I'm using Symfony 5.3.6 with PHP 8.0.9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You used a JSON field type, which expects an array instead of a string. So you shouldn't serialize it before setting.

You can use a [`object` type](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.9/reference/basic-mapping.html#doctrine-mapping-types) instead:

```
class Market
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="object")
     */
    protected Fee $fee;
}
```

(I also removed `@var Fee` because it's superfluous)

Comment: Eventually I decided not to save these data (these are tiny objects so I always build them on the fly), but your answer is helpful nonetheless and I will gladly use it in future. Thank you.